# Ignore an attribute value dynamically in drools rules

Tags: java, drools

I have a situation Where I need to ignore any attribute value at run time.

```
$applicant : Applicant ($age : age, $gender : gender, $income : income)
$person : Person( age == $age, gender == $gender, income == $income )
```

Say in income attribute, I am saying ANY value; it means if der is any value specified in application income attribute then it is ok otherwise also it should execute the rule because ANY value is acceptable.

Please help to implement this.

Thanks

Comment: Need some more info: What is it that you are trying to do here. The code above is similar to to a double for loop, .i.e. for each objectof type Applicant compare it with each object of Type Person provided certain attributes match. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: yes, but as i mentioned, on some point of time, income value is 0 and person object income would be say 1000 and also ANY it means that person object will take either 1000 as income or any value. It means I need to check for just two previous attributes and then if third attribute is ANY, I need to ignore this checking.

Comment: Answered below in coments, let me know if it helps.

Comment: @KedarParikh no it would not help dear. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a dynamic switch you need another object, `PersonControl` with boolean attributes:

```
$applicant : Applicant ($age : age, $gender : gender, $income : income)
PersonControl( $igAge: igAge, $igGender: ifGender, $igIncome: igIncome)
$person : Person( age == $age || $igAge,
                  gender == $gender || $igGender,
                  income == $income || $igIncome )
```

You may have to insert/retract (or modify) PersonControl for each Applicant evaluation if these evaluations need to be done individually.

If you want to state a value as any, you'll have to think about a value you can use for that, e.g. -1 for numeric values:

```
$applicant : Applicant ($age : age, $gender : gender, $income : income)
$person : Person( age == $age ,
                  gender == $gender,
                  income == $income || == -1 )
```

Comment: What is the use of escape characters as it is like `attributeName` == "some value". As I was reading in doc, I did not get it clearly. Thanks for your time.

Comment: attributeName is within escape `` characters.

Comment: No I was asking about the drools rule engine. http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.2.0.M2/drools-expert-docs/html/ch05.html  just top to section 5.3. I tried your way, it would solve my problem I hope. Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Ah, *that*. Forget about this feature, nobody needs to have Java object fields called `when` or `over`.

Comment: ok thank you very much for your solution. This is helping me a lot.

Comment: Please see this question. I have just posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28805373/how-to-achieve-below-objective-in-drools

Answer (score 0):

```
$applicant : Applicant ($age : age, $gender : gender, $income : income)
```

`$age : age` is an assignment, such that `$age` can be referred later on. and similarly with gender and income.

```
$person : Person( age == $age, gender == $gender, income == $income )
```

Here you are checking that age of every applicant to each of the person object and similarly with gender and income. So just to ignore any of them, just drop them from the equality checks.

i.e. So remove the conditions that you dont want to compare for equality, e.g. to ignore income:

```
rule "Compare Applicants"
salience 155 
when
    $applicant : Applicant ($age : age, $gender : gender)
    $person : Person( age == $age, gender == $gender )
then    
// do stuff
end
```

To ignore everything, i.e. to compare every applicant with every person and execute the `then` clause

```
when
 $applicant : Applicant ()
    $person : Person()
then
// do your stuff
end
```

Comment: Please check my comment dear. I need to mention the attributes in WHEN condition.

Comment: I gave a snippet, anyways edited to include code in when, then end. try it

Comment: @Kumar But omitting a constraint (e.g. `income == $income`) from a conditional element is the way to express that *any value matches*.

Comment: @laune I think I supposed to do so. if in person's income attribute comes with ANY, it will accept all value

Answer (score -1):

Can you just assign the applicant to `$applicant`, and then do the setting of `$age` and `$gender` in the `then` clause:

```
rule "do application"
when
    $applicant : Applicant()
    $person : Person( age == $age, gender == $gender, income == $income )
then
    $age = $applicant.getAge()
    // do more stuff
end
```