# How to achieve below objective in drools

Tags: java, drools

I am trying to do below things. Plesse check.

```
rule "new rule"
        salience -101
        dialect "mvel"
when
$pricingLineItem : PricingLineItem( $ackId : ackId, $prefix : prefix  )
$baseUpChargeConfig : BaseUpChargeConfig( $baseOptionId : baseOptionId,
                                          prefix == $prefix )
$pricingOptionType : PricingOptionType( ackId == $ackId,
                 $optionId : optionId, $optionValue : optionValue )
$baseOptionConfig : BaseOptionConfig( bOptionValue == $optionValue,
                   bOptionCode == $optionId ,id == $baseOptionId )
then
  $pricingLineItem.increment($baseOptionId);
  System.out.println("excuted - "+ $baseOptionId +" "+$baseOptionConfig);   
end
```

There will multiple BaseUpChargeConfig object match for one PricngLineItem. In the BaseUpChargeConfig object, we are getting all related BaseOptionConfig object and then trying to matche with PricingOptionType object of PricingLineItem. I need to take the best BaseUpChargeConfig object having maximum match with the PricingOptionType object of PricngLineItem.

**EDIT**

Say I have one PricingLineItem object with ackID, prefix value.
Now, I have multiple set of BaseUpChargeConfig object based on prefix value of PricingLineItem.

Now on ackId value, I have certain set of PricingOptionType object in rule engine.

and Also on baseOptionId value, I have multiple BaseOptionConfig object.

In PricingOptionType and BaseOptionConfig object, I need to compare the optioncode and option value.

If both are matching, I need to collect all matched pricing option type for a perticuler BaseUpChrageConfig.

In the same way, this will check for all other BaseUpChrageConfig object BaseOptionConfig and match.

Now the highest matched BaseOptionConfig object ; we will select that BaseUpChargeConfig as best object for our purpose.

I hope it would be clear for you.

Currently I am doing through java method by passing all three and calculating in java.

public void matchOptions(BaseUpChargeConfig config, List pricingOptionList,
        List baseOptionList) {

```
if ((pricingOptionList != null && !pricingOptionList.isEmpty())
        && (baseOptionList != null && !baseOptionList.isEmpty())) {

    List<PricingOptionType> matchedOption = null;
    matchedOption = new ArrayList<PricingOptionType>();
    for (PricingOptionType pOption : pricingOptionList) {
        int matchCount = 0;

        for (BaseOptionConfig bConfig : baseOptionList) {
            boolean optioncodeMatch = pOption.getOptionCode() == bConfig.getBaseOptionCode();
            boolean optionValueMatch = pOption.getOptionValue() == bConfig.getBaseOptionValue();
            if (optioncodeMatch && optionValueMatch) {
                matchedOption.add(pOption);
                matchCount++;
            }
        }
        if (matchCount > 0) {
            if (bestBaseUpChargeConfig != null) {
                optionMatchCount = matchCount;
                bestBaseUpChargeConfig = config;
                matchedPrcOptionList = matchedOption;
            } else if (matchCount == optionMatchCount) {
                bestBaseUpChargeConfig = null;
                matchedOption = null;
                matchedPrcOptionList.clear();
            } else if (matchCount > optionMatchCount) {
                optionMatchCount = matchCount;
                bestBaseUpChargeConfig = config;
                matchedPrcOptionList = matchedOption;
            } else {
                // do nothing
            }
        }
    }

} else {
    // do nothing
}
```

}

Thanks

Comment: This is almost impossible to unravel without an example showing objects for the various fact classes. Also, what is the measure where a maximum must be achieved?

Comment: There is no measure, the maximum match of all would be the winner.

Comment: If you could post the Java method, it would remove all doubts with minimum effort for me.

Comment: @laune Added java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This compiles with 5.5, so it shouldn't be a problem with 6.x either.

The duplication of the accumulate can't be helped unless you consider a more complicated evaluation involving derived facts.

```
rule "find best BaseUpChargeConfig"
when
// pick up some PricingLineItem
$pli: PricingLineItem( $prefix: prefix, $ackId : ackId )
// it should have a BaseUpChargeConfig with a matching prefix
$bucc: BaseUpChargeConfig( prefix == $prefix,
                           $baseOptionId : baseOptionId )
// count BaseOptionConfigs (linked to BaseUpChargeConfig) matching
// PricingOptionTypes, by option id/code and option value
accumulate(
    BaseOptionConfig( id == $baseOptionId,
                      $ocod: bOptionCode, $oval: bOptionValue )
    and          
    PricingOptionType( ackId == $ackId,
                       optionId == $ocod, optionValue == $oval );
      $count: count(1) )

// The $count computed above is the maximum if we don't have another
// BaseUpChargeConfig (for that prefix) where the count of the
// subordinate BaseOptionConfigs is greater than $count
not(
    ( BaseUpChargeConfig( this != $bucc,
                          prefix == $prefix,
                          $baseOptionId2 : baseOptionId )
      and
      accumulate(
          BaseOptionConfig( id == $baseOptionId2,
                            $ocod2: bOptionCode, $oval2: bOptionValue )
          and            
          PricingOptionType( ackId == $ackId,
                             optionId == $ocod2, optionValue == $oval2);
      $count2: count(1);
      $count2 > $count ) ) )
then
    System.out.println( "best BaseUpChargeConfig: " + $baseOptionId );
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable efforts. However, it is just passing through my head. :) Could U please elaborate; just some imp points enough. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Kumar Added some comments, HTH.