# Rules on arbitrary combinations of fact attributes

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine

I am a complete `Drools` noob. I have been tasked with implementing a set rule which, in the absence of nested rules, seems very complex to me. The problem is as follows:

I have a fact called `Person` with attributes `age`, `gender`, `income`, `height`, `weight` and a few others. A person may be classified as `level_1`, `level_2`, ..., `level_n` based on the values of the attributes. For example,

- `when` `age` < `a` and any value for other attributes `then`
  `classification` = `level_1`.
- `when` `gender` == `female` and any
  value for other attributes `then` `classification` = `level_2`.
- `when` `age` < `a` and `gender` == `female` and any value for other
  attributes `then` `classification` = `level_10`.
- ...

So, in any rule any arbitrary combination of attributes may be used. Can anyone help me in expressing this?

The second part of the problem is that the levels are ordered and if a person satisfies more than 1 rule, the highest level is chosen. The only way I can think of of ordering levels is to order the rules themselves using `salience`. So rules resulting is higher levels will have higher salience. Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28803397/341008) but that seems to deal with only 1 rule and the OP is probably more familiar with `Drools` than I am because I have not understood the solution. That talks about introducing a separate `control` fact but I didn't get how that works.

EDIT:
I would eventually have to create a template and supply the data using a csv. It probably does not matter for this problem, but, if it helps in any way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem of assigning a discrete value to facts of a type based on attribute combinations is what I call "classification problem" (cf. [Design Patterns in Production Systems](https://engage.redhat.com/forms/rule-design-patterns)). The simple approach is to write one rule for each discrete value, with constraints separating the attribute value cleanly from all other attribute sets. Note that statements such as

- when attribute value `age < a` and any value for other attributes then classify as level 1

are misleading and must not be used to derive rules, because, evidently, this isn't a correct requirement since we have

- when `age < a && gender == female` (...) then classify as level 10

and this contradicts the former requirement, correctly written as

- when `age < a && gender == male` then classify as level 1

Likewise, the specification for level 2 must also be completed (and it'll become evident that there is no country for old men). With this approach, a classification based on *i* attributes with just 2 intervals each results in 2<sup>n</sup> rules. If the number of resulting levels is anywhere near this number, this approach is best. For implementation a decision table is suitable.

If major subsets of the n-dimensional space should fall into the same class, a more economical solution should be used. If, for instance, all women should fall into the same level, a rule selecting all women can be written and given highest precedence; the remaining rules will have to deal with *n*-1 dimenions. Thus, the simplest scenario would require just *n* rules, one for each dimension.

It is also possible to describe other intervals in an n-dimensional space, providing the full set of values for all dimensions with each interval. Using the appropriate subset of values for each interval avoids the necessity of ordering the rules (using salience) and ensures that really all cases are handled. Of course, a "fall-through" rule firing with low priority if the level hasn't been set is only prudent.

Comment: Thank you, I see my mistake now. I have about 20 attributes and only 10 levels. I cannot however assign precedence to rules as I am not creating the rules. The plan is to provide a template and expose an api so that other teams can provide various parameter values using which we will generate the rules.

Comment: I am going through your whitepaper. It is  fantastically helpful. It is a slow read for me though as I am a beginner.